# Integral of variance of uncorrelated random number

Tags: integration, random, variance, dirac-delta

Given an uncorrelated, Guassian-distributed random number $\xi$ is unitary variance and zero mean, i.e. $\langle \xi\rangle  = 0$ and $\langle \xi(t)\xi(0)\rangle = \delta(t)$.

My question is:

If $\xi$ is unitary variance, does this mean $\langle \xi(0)\xi(0)\rangle = \delta(0)=1$?

If so, then could we still have $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\langle \xi(t)\xi(0)\rangle dt =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t)dt =1$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you may not be able to say $\delta(0)=1$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t)dt =1$ at the same time

Comment: Yes, I think so. But which one is the correct one?

Comment: I do not know but you seem to have some strange mixture of a Dirac delta and a Kronecker delta